# How Can I Active Virtual Environment Using .bat File?

Tags: python, django, cmd

I have finished working on Django project,
but I don't want to Deploy it to the server right now
I want to use this system on my local host.
I tried to create a file with bat extension, and this one is to open the project on the Chrome browser
This file will work when opened
The question is how with this file can I run the project virtual environment

The code that works is 'manager.bat':

```
start cmd /k start chrome http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
cd manager/venv/Manager 
python manage.py runserver
```

But when adding this statement:

```
activate
```

Then, when executing the file again, it exits the cmd without executing anything

Code not working:

```
start cmd /k start chrome http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
cd manager/venv
cd Scripts
activate
cd ..
cd Manager
python manage.py runserver
```

- 'activate' instruction is to activate the virtual environment , when I type it on cmd it works successfully ,, look :
  [enter image description here][1]
  The idea is that I don't want every time to open the cmd, run the virtual environment, and run the server manually

[This is on cmd and it works][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5XIe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Notepad and Write the following code, also change directory name as your need and save it as ***.bat file in your desktop

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d E:\ProjectsFolder\projectenv\Scripts & activate & cd /d    E:\ProjectsFolder\projectenv\myproject & python manage.py runserver"
```